# Kendo UI TreeView checkbox checked when load

Tags: kendo-ui

I had this [Kendo TreeView with checkbox](https://dojo.telerik.com/ajIBahIK). When load the treeview I want the checkbox is checked when `tick="y"`? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
tick="y"
```

do:

```
checked=true
```

See also https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/binding/check-nodes-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But somehow in my database it store the value 'y' and 'n' on that column. Is there any other options so I can use 'y' and 'n'?

Comment: if I replace `tick` to `checked` all checkbox will be checked. [demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ajIBahIK/6)

Comment: @dontbannedmeagain that's because JavaScript sees both 'y' and 'n' as true (see [truthy/falsy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) ). You can however store the data any way you want in your database and convert it in the dataSource's [parse](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schemaparse) function.